# AsyncImage with URLRequest

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am receiving an Image from my server with a post request using `URLRequest`.

I noticed that the `AsyncImage` view as for now, does not support a `URLRequest` as an input.

As for now, I have 2 options in mind:

1. Using `UIImage(data:)`
2. Building a custom AsyncImage something like in this link: https://www.donnywals.com/using-swifts-async-await-to-build-an-image-loader/

Are these really the only alternatives or perhaps I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.task()` modifier to your image in your view, like this:

```
    @State private var myImage: UIImage? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if myImage == nil {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                Image(uiImage: myImage!)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
            }
        }
        .task {
            let downloadedImage = await UIImage(data: myURLRequestHere())) ?? UIImage()      // URLRequest to return data
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                withAnimation {
                    myImage = downloadedImage
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It will work for iOS 15 on.

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main` is not needed. We are on the main thread.

Comment: `.task()` does not run on the `main` thread. If you don't use `DispatchQueue.main`, you'll get a "purple" error.

Comment: I just ran the code, no purple error and `Thread.isMainThread` returns `true`

Answer (score 0):

I would personally build a custom one with your needs.
I’ve recently tried it to get more in touch with combine publishers and it’s quite simple to get something decent, if you want to try/contribute/take it as example, feel free: [Simple iOS 13 AsyncImage](https://github.com/MarcBiosca/AsyncImage)

Answer (score -2):

You can download asyncImage with URL String Exemple:

```
AsyncImage(url: URL(string: imageURL)){image in
                image
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 75, height: 75)
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .cornerRadius(10)
```

Comment: I boldly emphasized that I am dealing with a `URLRequest`. not a `URL`!!!